# NavigationService.Navigate error

Tags: c#, navigationservice

I'm quite new on C# programming and I have a problem on my code.
I have created a button and applied on it an event click which open an other page of my project by the technology NavigationService.

This is the script:

```
private void click_login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this); 
    nav.Navigate(new Uri("Window1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

When I execute, I get this error:

```
The object reference is not set to an instance of an object with an InnerException null.
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: did you checked if nav is not null when your debugging this ? and here a some Remarks when [GetNavigationService returns null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have seen right, nav in null. Do I have to initiate with "new"?

Comment: No, please check the link i've provided in the remarks section there is a description when the GetNavigationService-Method returns null. There's probably something wrong with the `this` you are handing over to the method.

Comment: This returns 2 things: WpfApplication3.MainWindow which only have "InitializeComponent();" for the moment and the second thing is my button in mainwindow.xaml      Is that mean there's a conflict about what "this" mean?

Comment: Whats the type of your MainWindow ? Window?

Comment: Indeed, it's Window. Like this:                                 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nav object is null, because you're trying to get the NavigationService for a WPF Window.

But for Navigation you need a [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.aspx) ([Navigation Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#CreatingAXAMLPage))

A Little Working example:

Create to Page's Page1.xaml, Page2.xaml

In the App.xaml change the 
`StartupUri` to `StartupUri="Page1.xaml"`

**Page1 Xaml:**

```
 <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="Hello from  Page1" />
     <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Navigate to page 2"></Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

**Page1 cs:**

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        nav.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

**Page2 Xaml:**

```
 <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="Hello from  Page2" />
     <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Navigate to page 1"></Button>
 </StackPanel>
```

**Page2 cs:**

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        nav.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for my late, i come back from eat.
If i understand what you say, it's because i have created a window and not a page that i have a problem.
I create a new project and try your codes, i come to you quickly to tell you what happen.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Okay there it's works. Now i try to understand why.

On my project, i want to navigate from a window, my main window to an other window, window1
I have tried to navigate from my main window to a page called Page1.xaml, same error.
Have I to create an other page, containing the xaml code of the main window and redirecting the StartupUri to this page. (in order to get a page to page navigation?)

Comment: Okay now it works for my project. I have created a main page instead of a main window. Now i can navigate from the interface to the login by clicking on the button. I just have a last button, how can i call the next page like a pop-up and not like an other page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the NavigationService you can't navigate between Windows that's what the Page is for. If you want to have a popup the Navigation Service is not what you are looking for. There are several different ways how to open popups or dialogs in WPF for example [Window.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Popup Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx)